# How do mock a private or package protected class using PowerMockRunner?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'd like to override a method in a package protected class using PowerMock for some testing I'm doing on an Android project. I believe that's the proper way to do this so that I can proxy the methods that I'd like to proxy the calls into.

My tests live outside the package where the code under test lives.

Given the class: FooBar

```
package com.foo.bar
Class FooBar extends Object {
private void updateSomething(int Param1, String param2 ){
        //Do some work....
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a test case that mocks so that I can proxy the updateSomething method.

I envisioned something like this:

```
package com.example.test
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    @PrepareForTest({com.foo.bar.FooBar.class}) //<---COMPLAINT IS HERE
    public void test001_doTest() {
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the IDE complains that FooBar class is not public.

```
Error:(209, 55) error: FooBar is not public in com.foo.bar; cannot be accessed from outside package.
```

I thought that PowerMock was able to overcome this for free.
Any advise would be appreciated.

As an aside: I'd realize that I could use Reflection here. But where this method is called frequently, it's possible that I could set the test up, then something else change the value that I had set via mocking hence causing the test to fail erroneously (and intermittently). In this case, I believe it's better to proxy the class and methods. That's supposedly where Mockito and PowerMock shines?

Comment: If you are using `FooBar` in your tested code, then the code **must** be in the same package. So why test for the piece of code is in different package?

Comment: @MariuszMączkowski, the code under test is delivered as a java library (SDK) and utilized in a test app. This isn't unit testing, but more of SDK testing where we are testing functionality at a higher level, yet still need to control the inner dependencies.

Comment: It's weird if you must testing a library with isolating parts which are closed in this library.
You have compiler error. The only way is to use reflection and modify class access modifier, I think.

Comment: @MariuszMączkowski, I agree with your comments. I'm having to probably lean towards the Reflection methodology. That or just rename my test package to match that of the SDK that's being integrated into the app under test. Have not tried the latter...

Comment: Could you please elaborate: this method isn't static. So how do you intend to pass a **mocked** object of the Foo class into your class under test - given the fact that Foo isn't available? In other words: please show us what your test method is doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing implies that you are getting unit testing wrong.

In order to **isolate** a unit from its dependencies you mock the **objects** you are depend on.

Coming from there: given the fact that Foo is package protected - it should be **impossible** that *your* code directly references Foo. So the fact that you think about manipulating Foo is more of an indication that you put together a problematic design.

In that sense: I would recommend you to carefully look into your *need* to have control over Foo. Because in a *sane* design you should not have to worry about package protected classes outside of your scope. Invest your time to improve your design; instead of wasting time working around the **effects** of the broken design.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wholeheartedly agree. In a sane world, what you say is absolutely true. What about when you're a test engineer and you can't change the code you're testing? Convincing engineers that they need to change their code so you can test it is another challenge. We are NOT unit testing. We are System and API testing and need to be able to control some app internals that would only be detected by a cellular network. i.e. Detecting levels of congestion. Android testing of this level ain't for the faint of heart. We're having to get creative.